# why does my json have square brackets?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm investigating json with jquery and mvc2. I'm trying to create some json for an ajax post to my controller. I have an array created by this function

```
function getArguments() {
var argument1 = urlarray.slice(2, 3);
var argument2 = urlarray.slice(3, 4);
var argument3 = urlarray.slice(4, 5);
var argument4 = urlarray.slice(5);

return { Argument1: argument1, Argument2: argument2, Argument3: argument3, Argument4: argument4 }
}
```

I'm using json2.js to create the json like so

```
var data = getArguments();
var json = JSON.stringify(data);
```

when I look at the json it looks like this:

```
{"Argument1":["16"],"Argument2":["2"],"Argument3":["True"]}
```

This looks like valid json, but I don't understand the square brackets. I thought that was an array... anyone know why json2.js and its stringify would be putting in these brackets?... feel like I'm missing something obvious here.

Answer (score 8):

`.slice()` returns an array, even though you're slicing out only single values. Try something like:

```
var argument1 = urlarray[2];
var argument2 = urlarray[3];
etc...
```

which would return whatever's stored in those array slots (integer)?)

Comment: I think he forgot.